# AngularJS with $http

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing a custom directive for an onclick:

```
//add favourite
app.directive('addfavourite',
    function ($rootScope, $http) {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                //fire off $http
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: attrs['url']
                }).success(function (data, status) {
                        $rootScope.user_favourites = data.user_favourites
                    });
            });
        };
    });
```

I'm having a strange problem where the $http call never gets executed. There are no errors in the console, just nothing happens. If I put an alert inside the function prior to the $http call, it alerts, but the $http call never gets made. Am I doing something wrong?

Many thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from angularJS 1.1.4 you need to do scope.apply to kick off http, if it is not started from the context of an angular digest loop. So :

```
//add favourite
app.directive('addfavourite',
    function ($rootScope, $http) {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                //fire off $http
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: attrs['url']
                }).success(function (data, status) {
                        $rootScope.user_favourites = data.user_favourites
                    });
                // Run the digest loop :
                $rootScope.$apply();
            });
        };
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure?  This doesn't seem right.  Firstly, you are calling $apply after the http call, but before the result comes back.  Secondly, angular is calling your "success" callback for you, so you should not to do any sort of $scope.$apply in there...right?

Answer (score 0):

If you put alert in success(), you will see it gets called. However, you'd better handle the error as well.

```
function ($rootScope, $http) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function () {
            //fire off $http
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: attrs['url']
            }).success(function (data, status) {
                console.log('called');
                $rootScope.user_favourites = data.user_favourites
            }).error(function (data, status) {
                //error handling
            });
        });
    };
});
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HjLLQ/)**</kbd>

Comment: the problem is, in the console, it's not even firing off the request at all. Normally in chrome you can see the requests under the "network" tab.. not showing :(

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what is wrong just from the provided code, try to attach an error callback to `$http` like this:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: attrs['url']
}).success(function (data, status) {
    $rootScope.user_favourites = data.user_favourites
}).error(function() {
    console.log('error')
});
```

If the error callback has been called, that means your backend responded with an error. If the error callback hasn't been called, you can check the Network tab of chrome developer tools to see if the request has been made or not.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="text1" url="/api/testurl" addfavourite="addfavourite" ng-model="test"/>
```

directive:

```
angularApp.directive('addfavourite',
    function($rootScope, $http) {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                //fire off $http
                var u = attrs.url;
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',                  
                    url: u
                }).success(function(data, status) {
                    $rootScope.user_favourites = data.user_favourites
                });
            });
        };
    });
```

Comment: check console in firefox or network tab in chrome to see if request is made or not.